# Defining a mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For a supbspace $S$ of $V$, prove $L:V \rightarrow V$ such that $\ker(L)=S$. I am reviewing the answers posted in this link:

[For $\mathbb{S}$ subspace of $\mathbb{V}$, prove $L:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{V}$ such that Ker$(L)=\mathbb{S}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821590/739710)

How would we represent the linear mapping $L$ mathematically? Rather than saying "$L$ maps the basis vectors of $S$ to 0 and the other $n−k$ vectors to themselves."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just as you said.
Lets consider a function $L$ that sends the $k$ out of $n$ basis vectors, spanning S to $0$ and each of the remaining $n-k$ to itself. Then we are extend $L$ in a natural way as follows:

Let $u\in V$. Then $u=a_1e_1+ \dots + a_ne_n$ where $e_i$ are the basis vectors and $a_i\in \mathbb{K}$.
Then,
$$ L(u):= a_1 L(e_1) + \dots +a_nL(e_n)$$